# Exporting state variable not as a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I have a state as following in my App.tsx file

```
const [timeFrame, setTimeFrame] = useState('daily')
```

I also have another file, Card.tsx and I want to use timeFrame in Card.tsx file.

I know how to pass it as prop, but is there any way to export that state so that I can use

```
import timeFrame from "App.tsx"
```

Comment: You probably want to search for Custom Hooks and Context API. These provide a way to share state between Components. (1) https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#custom-hooks-sharing-logic-between-components (2) https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context

Comment: Yup, like @KostasMinaidis said - the answer is React's beloved context

Comment: Thank you @KostasMinaidis I just read them, they are really useful.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do that using `context`, but I prefer props for a scenario like that, also you can use `custom hook` if you need to separate logic from UI and also this is a good solution for a scenario like that for example:

```
// you can name the file as you wish for example useTimeFrame
import {useState} from 'react'
export const useTimeFrame = () => {
  const [timeFrame, setTimeFrame] = useState('daily');
  return {timeFrame, setTimeFrame}
}
// in your Card.tsx file
import {useTimeFrame} from './useTimeFrame.hook.ts'
const {timeFrame, setTimeFrame} = useTimeFrame()
```

also, I noticed you used `Typescript` so specify the type of the `state` as a clean code.
I hope my answer fit your question, let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thank you for your return, it is just what I asked for, but yeah now I think same as you, prop is better.

Comment: props are useful when you need to reuse the component but if not you don't need that you can just use the custom hook as I mentioned in the above example, and keep your component as simple as possible to prevent unnecessary re-rendering.